# Load table with GEOMETRY column to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, gis

I am trying to load table (from Postgres DB) with GEOMETRY column to Pandas DataFrame using `pd.read_sql_table` method. I am getting error becuase GEOMETRY type seem to be not supported:

*C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\base.py:3010: SAWarning: Did not recognize type 'geometry' of column 'geometry' "Did not recognize type '%s' of column '%s'" % (attype, name)*

Does anyone knows how to load such data to Pandas df? On Pandas Doc page for "read_sql_table" I don't see options to define column data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[just GeoPandas](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) , install it

```
git clone https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git
cd geopandas
pip install .
```

It is also possible to install the latest development version directly from the GitHub repository with:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git
```

For installing GeoPandas from source, the same note on the need to have all dependencies correctly installed applies. But, those dependencies can also be installed independently with conda before installing GeoPandas from source:

```
conda install pandas fiona shapely pyproj rtree
```

and use the [from_postgis](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis) method like this :

```
import geopandas as gpd
sql = "SELECT ST_asBinary(geom) AS geom, highway FROM roads"
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql, con)
```